# Detecting "short segments" in a File Geodatabase Feature Class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase

Using ArcMap 10.3 (without any extensions) is there a way to detect "short segments" in a feature class that is part of a file geodatabase automatically (without having to zoom to each feature to inspect manually)?

"short" is defined by a value the user enters. "segment" refers to the distance between successive vertices in a polygon or polyline.

Comment: define short? you can calculate lengths and filter on that.

Comment: @mapperz not the length of the polyline, the length of the segments between vertices.Short = user defined

Comment: Ok, I removed my down vote, after you rephrase question. Very simple field calculator expression will do a job

Comment: How about using the Split Lines at Vertices tool followed by a SQL query? http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-vertices.htm